# ¿Por qué mi tabla de MarkDown en Django no se formatea correctamente?

Tags: django, markdown

¡Hola! Estoy intentado cargar una tabla en markdown que tengo en mi base de datos y la estructura y su contenido son de prueba, pero acá está:

```
First Header  | Second Header
------------- | -------------
Content Cell  | Content Cell
Content Cell  | Content Cell
```

Acá el controlador

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from inventory.models import Products, Categories
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.http import Http404
import markdown

def product_view(request, product_name):
    
    try:
        product = Products.objects.get(slug=product_name)
    except Products.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("El producto no existe")
        
    descripcion_1_md = markdown.markdown(product.descripcion_1)
    descripcion_2_md = markdown.markdown(product.descripcion_2)
    
    return render(request, 'products/product.html', {"producto": product, 'descripcion_1_md': descripcion_1_md, "descripcion_2_md": descripcion_2_md})
```

Y acá el elemento de la vista:

```
<div class="col-span-2 text-center prose md:prose-md lg:prose-lg mx-auto hidden sm:flex flex-col gap-4 hover:prose-h4:underline">
    {{descripcion_2_md | safe}}      
</div>
```

Acá una imagen de como se debería ver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y acá el como se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano :)